# Regarding the motion of a rod hinged at one end

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics, angular-velocity

A rod of length $L$ is hinged at one end. It is brought to the horizontal position and released. What is the angular velocity of the rod when it is in the vertical position?

According to me, the rod will behave as if its entire mass is concentrated at the non-hinged end. Then by energy considerations,

$$mgL = \frac{1}{2}mv^2$$

which gives,

$$v^2 = 2gL$$

substituting $v = \omega L$, we get,

$$\omega = \sqrt{\frac{2g}{L}}$$

However, my book says the answer is $\sqrt{\frac{3g}{L}}$.

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: @HEIFETZ The entire mass of the rod can be assumed to be concentrated at the center of mass of the rod. The axis of rotation passes through the hinged end but the center of mass is not located at the non-hinged end. For a rod whose mass is uniformly distributed across its length, the center of mass is located at the midpoint of the rod.

Comment: @YashasSamaga : Using $v=\frac12L\omega$ is more consistent but still gives the wrong answer.

Comment: @sammygerbil It is $\frac{1}{2}I\omega ^2$ not $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$.

Comment: @SNB No, there is no relative motion between the particles in the rod, because the rod is assumed to be rigid. Regarding COM, Ketan's answer is correct. In a uniform gravitational field, the change in PE of the COM is the same as the change in PE of the whole body, because $\Delta$PE is proportional to change in average height. However, the KE of a body is not usually the same as the KE of the COM, because while the velocity $v$ of the CM is the average velocity of all particles in the body, $v^2$ for the COM is not necessarily the same as the average $v^2$ for all particles.

Answer (score 2):

First of all whole mass of rod will be assumed to be concentrated at its center for calculation of change in potential energy. Hence 
$ \Delta PE = \frac{MgL}{2}$. Also, you need to consider kinetic energy of rigid body around hinge instead of considering it for point mass - $ KE = \frac{1}{2}I\omega^2 $

Hence,
$$ \Delta PE = \frac{MgL}{2} = \Delta KE = \frac{1}{2}I\omega^2 $$

$$ I = \frac{ML^2}{3} $$
$ \omega $ follows.

Comment: Can you add the final answer?

Comment: @YashasSamaga : Site policy is that complete answers to homework-like questions should not be given, and are liable to be deleted. See http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7638/should-we-suggest-that-authors-of-complete-solutions-to-homework-like-questions